# Ubuntu Scope with Framework 14.10 - Intltool

Tags: 14.10, application-development, compiling, ubuntu-sdk

Recently, I want to create a scope project, but then I found the following error when running CMake:

> CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:26 (find_package):
>     By not providing "FindIntltool.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
>     asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Intltool",
>     but CMake did not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Intltool" with any
>     of the following names:

```
IntltoolConfig.cmake
intltool-config.cmake
```

> Add the installation prefix of "Intltool" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
>     "Intltool_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
>     "Intltool" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
>     been installed.

Is there any work around?

Answer (score 1):

It says that "FindIntltool.cmake" is not provided.

This file is distributed in the `cmake-extras` package.

Install it in the chroot (kit) that is used to build the project.